# Convert SQL native query to Spring data JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to convert MySQL native query to Spring data JPA Query.

```
@Query(value = "FROM PD p where p.pT = :pT AND p.fY = :fY "
            + " AND p.Ew.eId in (SELECT ew.eId FROM Ew ew WHERE ew.o.oId in ( :oId ) )")
    List<PD> test(@Param("pT")String pT,@Param("year") Integer year,@Param("oId")String oId);
```

**I get an exception**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [265,295,296] did not match expected type [java.lang.Integer (n/a)]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.validateBinding(BaseQueryImpl.java:892)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.access$000(QueryImpl.java:61)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl$ParameterRegistrationImpl.bindValue(QueryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.BaseQueryImpl.setParameter(BaseQueryImpl.java:637)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:163)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.setParameter(AbstractQueryImpl.java:32)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:150)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.StringQueryParameterBinder.bind(StringQueryParameterBinder.java:61)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bind(ParameterBinder.java:111)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.bind(SpelExpressionStringQueryParameterBinder.java:69)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.ParameterBinder.bindAndPrepare(ParameterBinder.java:163)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.doCreateQuery(AbstractStringBasedJpaQuery.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.createQuery(AbstractJpaQuery.java:169)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$CollectionExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:114)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:78)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:91)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:462)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:440)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
... 85 more
```

Any Help should be appreciated !

Comment: You put "nativeQuery=true" ... so it expects SQL, yet you didnt provide SQL. FWIW JPQL starts with "SELECT {alias}", otherwise you consign yourself to provider specific for no benefit (i.e a daft decision)

Comment: @DN1 oh yeah there is i need to remove native query = true from HQL..
Let me try . Thanks

Comment: @DN1 I edited my question.

Comment: @DN1 Got it now , I need to pass array instead of comma separated string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is works !

I need to pass Array List of ids instead of comma separated string

```
 @Param("oId")List<Integer> oId
```